# lubuntu - command to use in .desktop file to launch application reduced to panel

Tags: lubuntu, system-tray, .desktop, lxpanel

I have a .desktop file:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Encoding=UTF-8
Name=Thunderbird
Comment=mail manager
Exec=thunderbird
Terminal=false
Type=Application
NoDisplay=false
Hidden=false
```

Is there a command to use in this file to let application running directly reduced to system panel?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I'm posting a method that may work providing nothing else you've done conflicts and it applies if you have a default Lubuntu 13.04 with Openbox managing your windows. Also, **please** read [How do I open specific applications on specific workspaces in Lubuntu 13.04](https://askubuntu.com/a/290197/25656) in which I've covered other essential aspects (and omitted here).

In brief, you need to create a subsection in the `applications` section of `~/.config/openbox/lubuntu-rc.xml` for Thunderbird. The subsection would look like this:

```
<application name="..." class="...">
  <iconic>yes</iconic>
</application>
```

I'm purposely not being specific about `...` because I don't have Thunderbird installed. But, you should be able to figure out what has to be inserted in place of both occurrences of `...` after you read about `xprop` in the linked answer. *If the solution works for you, could you please come back and post the exact contents you use?*

Here is code that makes `gedit` and `Firefox` open "iconic" which is the term `Openbox` uses to describe apps in a minimized state:

```
<application name="gedit" class="Gedit">
  <iconic>yes</iconic>
</application>

<application name="Navigator" class="Firefox">
  <iconic>yes</iconic>
</application>
```

<sup>If you're interested in using `lubuntu-rc.xml` further, also look at [Launching Windows Maximized](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Lubuntu/Windows#Launching_Windows_Maximized) and the section that follows.</sup>

Caveat: **this procedure may not work for everything!** I couldn't get `Transmission` to open iconified with this code:

```
<application type="*" name="transmission-gtk" class="Transmission-gtk">
  <iconic>yes</iconic>
</application>
```